# Perform segue with UIAlertAction

Tags: ios, swift, segue, uialertcontroller, uialertaction

I would like to have the "Next" button perform segue to move to "PersonalInformation" (a UIViewController)

But I get a "signal SIGABRT" with the code..
How can I fix it?

```
let alert = UIAlertController(title:"Confirmation", message: confirmationMessage, preferredStyle: UIAlertControllerStyle.Alert)

let confirmBtn : UIAlertAction = UIAlertAction(title: "Next", style: UIAlertActionStyle.Default, handler: {(action:UIAlertAction!)-> Void in

    self.performSegueWithIdentifier("PersonalInformation", sender: self)

})

let cancelBtn : UIAlertAction = UIAlertAction(title: "Cancel", style: UIAlertActionStyle.Cancel, handler: nil)

alert.addAction(cancelBtn)
alert.addAction(confirmBtn)

self.presentViewController(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

Comment: Where is the SIGABRT occurring?  In `performSegueWithIdentifier` or somewhere else?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is mainly caused by wrong storyboard or xib/nib connections, make sure that you have the right connections in storyboard that have the next button or the one you are moving to.

Comment: thanks!! i forgot to set the Storyboard ID...

Comment: one more question.. is there any way i can pass an array to the next ViewController at the same time?

Comment: like moving the prepareforsegue function into it or what?

Comment: there is a lot of ways to do that, you will definitely find someone who asked this before in stack overflow, just search for "segue array" and you will find a lot of answered questions, good luck.